# Appropriate C# Stream Object

Tags: c#, stream

Which Stream object can i write to using StreamWriter and then get the contents as a string?

```
StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter(streamObject);
string s = streamObject.getString (); // or something like that
```

EDIT:
here is the full code, instead of writing to a file, I want to write to a stream object in memory and then get the contents as a string:

```
  static void DecryptFile(string sInputFilename,
      string sOutputFilename,
      string sKey) {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            //A 64 bit key and IV is required for this provider.
            //Set secret key For DES algorithm.
            DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
            //Set initialization vector.
            DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

            //Create a file stream to read the encrypted file back.
            FileStream fsread = new FileStream(sInputFilename,
               FileMode.Open,
               FileAccess.Read);
            //Create a DES decryptor from the DES instance.
            ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
            //Create crypto stream set to read and do a 
            //DES decryption transform on incoming bytes.
            CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread,
               desdecrypt,
               CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            //Print the contents of the decrypted file.
            StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(sOutputFilename);
            fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());
            fsDecrypted.Flush();
            fsDecrypted.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? StreamWriter exists to WRITE on a stream, it seems that you are trying to READ from the underlying stream

Comment: If you need to get string, you should use StreamReader()

Comment: @Steve  YES, I want a stream object that I can write to using StreamWriter then get the contents a s a string

Comment: Then finish to write and then reopen with a StreamReader. However if you are just start writing in that file you already know what you are writing.

Comment: Please use [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to open a Stream and auto close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your edits, instead of this:

```
//Print the contents of the decrypted file.
StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(sOutputFilename);
fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());
fsDecrypted.Flush();
fsDecrypted.Close();
```

you can write this:

```
static string DecryptFile(string sInputFilename, string sKey)
{
    using (var DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

        using (var fsread = new FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
        using (var desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor())
        using (var cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread, desdecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr))
        {
            // this is a stream content as a string, you don't need to write and read it again
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Also note, that your code misses `using`s for `IDisposable` implementations.

Answer (score 2):

```
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("testing a string");
    }

    byte[] contentBytes = ms.ToArray();
    string content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contentBytes);
```